# How to modify a tikzposter title style?

Tags: tikzposter

## What I want

I would like to use the Wave titlestyle that I found in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzposter/tikzposterTitlestyles.tex` on my Kubuntu 14.4. However I'd like to have the top to be smaller in vertical size.

## What I tried

I tried

```
\usetitlestyle[titletotopverticalspace=-100mm,]{Wave}
```

but this also brought the title text up.

I tried to copy the code from `tikzposterTitlestyles.tex` and to manipulate it, but

```
\definetitlestyle{mytitlestyle}{
    width=\paperwidth, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0pt, innersep=1.5cm,
    titletotopverticalspace=0mm, titletoblockverticalspace=20mm,
    titlegraphictotitledistance=10pt, titletextscale=1
}{
    \coordinate (topleft) at (\titleposleft,\titlepostop);
    \coordinate (topright) at (\titleposright,\titlepostop);
    \coordinate (lefttoright) at (\titlewidth,0);
    \coordinate (head) at (0,\titlepostop-\titleposbottom);
    %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=blocktitlebgcolor!90!black, right color=titlebgcolor!95]%
        (topright) -- (topleft) -- %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,6)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,6) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,9)$) and %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.5*(lefttoright) - (-10,16)$) .. %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) -- cycle;
%     %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=blocktitlebgcolor, right color=white] %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-6,3) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) and ($(topright) -
        (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,17)$).. %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) .. controls %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright)-(-7,19)$) and %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-9,5) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) .. %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,4)$);
    %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=white, right color=blocktitlebgcolor!90!black]%
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-6,3) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) and ($(topright) -
        (head)+(0,6) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,20)$)..%
        ($(topright) - (head)+(0,6)$) -- %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) .. controls %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,17)$) and %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-8,4) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) .. %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$);

    \setlength{\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}{5\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
```

already threw errors like

```
! You can't use `the character 0' after \the.
\titlepostop ->0
                .5\paperheight 
l.197 

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.197 

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.197 


! Package calc Error: `@' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.197 

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \TP 

l.197 

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.197 

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.197 

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> 5\TP 
                @titletoblockverticalspace
l.197 

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \TP 

l.197 

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \TP 
               @titletoblockverticalspace
l.197 

! You can't use `the character @' after \the.
<argument> \TP @
                titletoblockverticalspace
l.197
```

and enclosing `\setlength{\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}{5\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}` with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` did not help.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer in the sense that the title is modified, but I can tell you what is wrong with the code you've showed us:

1. The empty line before the `\setlength`. Paragraph breaks are not allowed there, so you need to either remove the blank line, or add a `%`, as you can see other places.
2. The `@`. To use `@` in macro names in the preamble, you need to add `\makeatletter` before the code and `\makeatother` after, see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351).

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Wave}
\author{A not so frustrated user}
\title{A pretty enough poster I hope}

\makeatletter % added
\definetitlestyle{mytitlestyle}{
    width=\paperwidth, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0pt, innersep=1.5cm,
    titletotopverticalspace=0mm, titletoblockverticalspace=20mm,
    titlegraphictotitledistance=10pt, titletextscale=1
}{%
    \coordinate (topleft) at (\titleposleft,\titlepostop);
    \coordinate (topright) at (\titleposright,\titlepostop);
    \coordinate (lefttoright) at (\titlewidth,0);
    \coordinate (head) at (0,\titlepostop-\titleposbottom);
    %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=blocktitlebgcolor!90!black, right color=titlebgcolor!95]%
        (topright) -- (topleft) -- %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,6)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,6) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,9)$) and %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.5*(lefttoright) - (-10,16)$) .. %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) -- cycle;
%     %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=blocktitlebgcolor, right color=white] %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-6,3) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) and ($(topright) -
        (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,17)$).. %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) .. controls %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright)-(-7,19)$) and %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-9,5) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) .. %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,4)$);
    %
    \draw[draw=none, left color=white, right color=blocktitlebgcolor!90!black]%
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$) .. controls %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-6,3) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) and ($(topright) -
        (head)+(0,6) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,20)$)..%
        ($(topright) - (head)+(0,6)$) -- %
        ($(topright) - (head)$) .. controls %
        ($(topright) - (head) - 0.25*(lefttoright) - (-6,17)$) and %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(-8,4) + 0.25*(lefttoright) + (0,10)$) .. %
        ($(topleft) - (head)-(0,2)$);
% added the percent character here
    \setlength{\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}{5\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother

% make this style active
\usetitlestyle{mytitlestyle}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [tikzposter manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf) you can pass arguments for title 
customization in `\maketitle` macro.

What you need is setting the `titletoblockverticalspace` option. Other useful options are `width` `titletotopverticalspace`, `titletextscale`.

E.g something like the following should work

```
\maketitle[titletoblockverticalspace=0mm]
```

Comment: Nice answer. if you set negative space to `titletotopverticalspace`, the title block shrinks. Not sure if there are side effects yet.